# Access The Mobile Device's Blocked Contacts With React Native and Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, expo

I am building a React native mobile app using Expo. I am trying to access the phone numbers that are blocked in the device. I have tried using the expo-contacts library, but the contact information does not include if the contact is blocked or not. Is it possible to access this list with another library? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you developing for Android/iOS or both? Android doesn't allow you to fetch a list of blocked contacts (see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#number-blocking)

Comment: @AlexCatchpole my intent is to develop this app for both using Expo. Do you know if iOS does? thanks

Comment: did not find solution?